# incompatible devices with new apk update

Tags: android, version, backwards-compatibility

I updated a new apk in my developer console, but it seems to be supported by a lower number of devices . my previous was supported by 100 more devices. I don't know what is not supported, but I saw that the new apk has 2 more functions:

android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT

android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE

Can you help me please?
following is my build.gradle.

[build.gradle](http://www.ipronosticididelfi.com/build.txt)

and here is my manifest.xml:

[manifest.xml](http://www.ipronosticididelfi.com/manifest.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Appodeal which needed a higher min-sdk version.. I just changed the ad network and everything was ok